Cases with no skill set getting assigned to agent
We are working on a omnichannel requirement and assigning the skill to cases via custom invocable class. However in some of the scenarios cases which are not matching with any skill are getting assigned to the skilled agent.
Is it working as designed as my thought was they will remain in the backlog if there are no matching skill or cases have zero matched skill record assigned.
Is this a standard functionality or there is something missing in the config.

Utilize the Omni-Supervisor tool to monitor the assignment of cases and ensure that cases without matching skills remain in the backlog. This tool can help identify and troubleshoot routing issues.
